# Zooming into a Clutter CairoTexture while re-drawing

Tags: python, zooming, cairo, scaletransform, clutter

I am using python-clutter 1.0

**My question in the form of a challenge**

Write code to allow zooming up to a CairoTexture actor, by pressing a key, in steps such that at each the actor can be re-drawn (by cairo) so that the image remains high-res but still scales as expected, *without* re-sizing the actor.

Think of something like Inkscape and how you can zoom into the vectors; how the vectors remain clean at any magnification. Put a path (bunch of cairo `line_to` commands, say) onto an CairoTexture actor and then allow the same trick to happen.

**More detail**

I am aiming at a small SVG editor which uses groups of actors. Each actor is devoted to one path. I 'zoom' by using `SomeGroup.set_depth(z)` and then make z bigger/smaller. All fine so far. However, the closer the actor(s) get to the camera, the more the texture is stretched to fit their new apparent size.

I can't seem to find a way to get Clutter to do both:

1. Leave the actor's actual size static (i.e. what it started as.)
2. Swap-out its underlying surface for larger ones (on zooming in) that I can then re-draw the path onto (and use a cairo matrix to perform the scaling of the context.)

If I use `set_size` or `set_surface_size`, the actor gets *larger* which is not intended. I only want it's *surface* (underlying data) to get larger.

(I'm not sure of the terminology for this, mipmapping perhaps? )

Put another way: a polygon is getting larger, increase the size of its texture array so that it can map onto the larger polygon.

I have even tried an end-run around clutter by keeping a second surface (using pycairo) that I re-create to the apparent size of the actor (`get_transformed_size`) and then I use clutter's `set_from_rgb_data` and point it at my second surface, forcing a re-size of the surface but not of the actor's dimensions.

The problem with this is that a)clutter ignores the new size and only draws into the old width/height and b)the RGBA vs ARGB32 thing kind of causes a colour meltdown.

I'm open to any alternative ideas, I hope I'm standing in the woods missing all the trees!

\d

Answer (score 2):

Well, despite all my tests and hacks, it was right under my nose all along.

Thanks to Neil on the clutter-project list, here's the scoop:

```
CT = SomeCairoTextureActor()

# record the old height, once:
old_width, old_height = CT.get_size()

Start a loop:
# Do stuff to the depth of CT (or it's parent)
...

# Get the apparent width and height (absolute size in pixels)
appr_w,appr_h = CT.get_transformed_size()

# Make the new surface to the new size
CT.set_surface_size( appr_w, appr_h )

# Crunch the actor back down to old size 
# but leave the texture surface something other!
CT.set_size(old_width, old_height)

loop back again
```

> The surface size and the size of the
>   actor don't have to be the same. The
>   surface size is just by default the
>   preferred size of the actor. You can
>   override the preferred size by just
>   setting the size on the actor. If the
>   size of the actor is different from
>   the surface size then the texture will
>   be squished to fit in the actor size
>   (which I think is what you want).

Nice to put this little mystery to bed. Thanks clutter list!

\d